# Is there any way to limit the size of s3 bucket by configuration on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, limit, cloud-storage

According to the use case providing temporary storage as a service where particular s3 bucket for this purpose  will be used. I wonder if there is a way to limit the number of objects that will be stored and/or size of the bucket(storage) by configuration or tweaking bucket properties

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no such property or settings. You have to develop a **custom solution** for that yourself.

Depending how strict you have to be about the size of your buckets there are few general solutions you could consider:

1. Each upload triggers a lambda function which checks **CloudWatch Metric** `BucketSizeBytes` or `NumberOfObjects` for your bucket. These metrics are updated **once a day** so you can overshot your limits.
2. Each upload triggers a lambda function, which stores size of each object in **DynamoDB table**. At the same time you query the table for current size of the bucket. This solves the issue of the first approach but requires more development and maintenance.

One could think of other ways, more tailored to your specific use case, but that requires more details, such as can your object be uploaded over API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks,  yes uploads(objects) typically go through API gateway and will be using lambda

Comment: @neotam In this case your lambda would do these checks before uploading the object to S3, rather then after uploading.